# Even after I win a hand, Zynga poker won't show me the hole cards from other players

Tags: rules, online

Playing Zynga poker on my phopne. One thing that gives me grief is that I make it all the way to the River, win the hand, but without getting to see the hole cards from other players who went the distance with me.  This happens about half the time when I win. I want to know what the other player had when he raised, as that would tell me something about his betting behavior.

Take the picture below. I had never raised during the series, only checking and calling until the end.  I win, but no reveal of what the hole cards from the other two were.

Does Zynga have a bug here by not having everyone reveal their hole cards during the showdown?  Or is it implementing a rotation by which each player takes turns turning over his cards (and auto-folding losers)?

[image]

Comment: I don't use it,  so I can't say for certain, but many sites have an option to auto-muck a losing hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully another better later than never response!-)

Zynga poker is revealing hands in order and auto mucking losing hands.

They have been slow in adding new features at the table in the past but have recently added new game modes (Omaha, Short Deck, Pineapple).

I wouldn’t be surprised to see more user requested features especially if they add to all game modes, so I would say be vocal and get any buddies to add as a request on their Facebook page or through CS.

Comment: Late answers are always more appreciated than no answers.  Thanks Peter!

Comment: Ask zynga tech support

Answer (score 1):

Players don't have to show you their losing hands if they choose to muck said hands. It doesn't just happen on Zynga Poker, but players can choose to muck their losing hand on any platform!

Here is an article on mucking hands: https://automaticpoker.com/poker-basics/what-is-a-muck-in-poker/

Comment: LOL - four years later, someone drops a non-answer and tadpoles me.  You da man, @JasonCGould!

Comment: Better late than never ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don play there and would suggest you ask there. I would guess though they use a normal order of showdown starting at the last player to bet during the last round of betting. Generally speaking people don't have to show losers unless they make a bet you call.

Comment: LOL.  There's no "asking there".

Comment: But OP said they never bet during the hand.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to see losing hands after they fold. It's a good feature so players WON'T reveal their strategies. That's the way you play poker; by not revealing strategies. So good for Zynga if they aren't showing hole cards in such cases. And I'm glad they don't cause I don't wish for you to know my strategies. The same applies when you win, and choose not to reveal your winning hand or strategy. It's called a "muck" feature. And in most sites you can turn it ON or OFF (if you turn it ON or leave it ON (usually ON by default), you're smart, if OFF or choose to boast and show your cards like some dumb and cocky monkeys I sometimes see who reveal their hands to sometimes "show-off" or just for "show", then the muckers will get the last laugh baby. Some kids are so cocky and dumb, and I love taking their chips, which is likely their Daddy's money, anyway. Glad that Zynga has "auto-muck" (I hope they do at least), cause I don't see a check box for mucking. Mucking means you never show your cards whether you win or lose PROVIDED you folded if you lost or everyone else has folded if you win (especially when you win, not just lose like your case above). And by the way, if you play poker for real money, you're a fool baby.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Zynga has a "Show/Muck" option, but it defaults to "Show" after every hand. I, like many others, do not want my opponents to know what my hole cards are when I fold or win a hand after others have folded, but I cannot find a way to change the default to "Muck" (where it should be, not visa versa), or to opt out of the option altogether. I have searched the settings but to no avail. Zynga is already giving too much information away on how players  structure their strategy, and they have just added to that. If there IS a way to change this, I would really like to know.